# Why won't Python's "\x1B[1A" work in Google Colab? It works in my other debugger

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to make a program that plays a maze game in the python console. I have it set up so it looks like its updating instead of just reprinting the same lines with a one character difference over and over again. So far it looks like this (shorted to only show problem)

```
#makes the print statement clear the line before printing a new one
oprint = print
def print(this, pre = CLR, end = "\n"):
    oprint(pre+this, end = end)
#lets you move the cursor up
def moveUp(times):
    for i in range(times):
        print(UP, end = "")
```

In my fist debugger it worked perfectly no problems at all but in Colab it just doesn't work. I don't think it's a problem with the code but I was more wondering if there's a certain setting I have to turn on for it to work properly. My problem is more because I want to share the game with friends who have visual studio code on there computers. I only have the online ones, such as Google Colab.

Comment: What shell does Colab run? Those terminal escape sequences work in specific terminals, they're not portable at all.

Comment: "My problem is more because I want to share the game with friends who have visual studio code on there computers. I only have the online ones, such as Google Colab." I dont understand your problem really.